# Recurrence event Google Calendar Request Failed

Tags: javascript, api, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-calendar-recurring-events

I am working on Google Calendar Service and I have problem with "Recurrence Event". Here is my code:
[image]

And in catch I got a error message: "Request failed". I don know why because in Interface "ICalendarEvent" I have recurrence. Here is the par of code in Interface:
[image]

I am first time working with Google provider and I can say that I am a beginner :) If someone can help me please add comment. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please copy+paste your code rather than using screenshots?

Comment: Hello Rafa. We need to send a timeZone after start.dateTime and end.dateTime. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed. We must to send a timeZone too.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Da6t.png)